# Lidar intensity value normalization

Tags: python, c#, windows, robotics, lidar-data

We have a file with X,Y,Z,I in binary format, We want to convert this to las file with intensity values, But the intensity values range from 1 to 11629. Las file supports the intensity value between 0 to 255, Could anyone suggest on how to create las file with these intensity values?

```
var curIntensity = 525;
var maxInensity = 11629;
var fact = 255.0 / maxInensity;
var nIntensity = curIntensity * fact;

nIntensity = 11
```

tried to normalize with above formula, But results are not excepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is 1-based, while the output is 0-based, so you should normalize the base first:

```
var curIntensity = 525;
var maxInensity = 11629;
var fact = 255.0 / (maxInensity - 1);
var nIntensity = (curIntensity - 1) * fact;
```